# How to ignore errors, but not skip lines in COPY command redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have the below COPY statement. It skips lines for maxerror. Is there any way to COPY data over to redshift, forcing any errors into the column regardless of type? I dont want to lose information.

```
sql_prelim = """copy table1 from 's3://dwreplicatelanding/file.csv.gz' 
            access_key_id 'xxxx' 
            secret_access_key 'xxxx' 
            DELIMITER '\t' timeformat 'auto'
            GZIP IGNOREHEADER 1 
            trimblanks
            CSV
            BLANKSASNULL
            maxerror as 100000
            """
```

The error I want to skip is below, but ideally I want to skip all errors and maintain data:

```
   1207-  Invalid digit, Value 'N', Pos 0, Type: Decimal
```

Comment: change all the column datatypes to varchar.

Comment: @RahulGupta how could I do that from the copy statement?

Comment: You don't do it from the COPY statement — you would need to change your table definition so that every column has a type of `VARCHAR`. This, of course, will ruin any queries you have that expect different column types, but at least the data will be loaded. So, I would recommend creating a _temporary_ table with all `VARCHAR`, load the data into it, then copy the data from this temporary table into the normal table (with some type conversions).